# Некорректно выводит в консоль рускоязычные символы

Tags: c++

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZW31.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.